# jQuery Cloud Zoom: activate script via click instead of hover

Tags: jquery

As the title suggests I'm looking for a way to initiate the jQuery Cloud Zoom script so that it runs when the user clicks an element on the page and not when hovering an image.
I've tried the official forum for the plugin but with no luck, perhaps someone here has created a similar solution before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#itemToZoom').Click(new function(){
        $(this).CloudZoom();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom(); 
        $('#cloudZoom').click(function(){
            $('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();      
            return false;
        })

    });
```

Comment: Worth noting that this solution preserved the behaviour of clicking on alternative images to replace the main zoomable one, whereas the accepted answer didn't quite manage that.

Answer (score 0):

since version V3.0 rev 1302271415 you can achieve this behavior by setting the cloudzoom option "mouseTriggerEvent".

Example:

html:

```
<a href="/link/to/big/img.jpg" class="zoom">
    <img src="/link/to/small/img.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" />
</a>
```

js:

```
jQuery('a.zoom img').CloudZoom({mouseTriggerEvent: 'click'});
```

See all available options [Cloud Zoom Quickstart Guide](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change directly in cloudjs file mousemove............replace mousemove to click event